# CentOS can't join Active Directory domain with specific DC server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, centos6.5

We are trying to join a CentOS 6.5 to AD domain specifying a certain DC server (Windows), to test squid authentication with the new Win Server 2012 R2 domain controllers. We previously had 3 domain controllers in our main office, (two 2008 R2 and one 2012(non-R2)). This week we added 2 more dc's (both 2012 R2) to replace the old ones. Well, the point is our test CentOS can't join domain using one of the new DCs. For example when using

```
/usr/bin/net ads join -S DC4.Somedomain.local -U DomainUser
```

It fails and we get:

> Failed to join domain: failed to lookup DC info for domain
>   'Somedomain.local' over rpc: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET

But when we just change the DC name to the other 2012 R2 DC:

```
/usr/bin/net ads join -S DC5.Somedomain.local -U DomainUser
```

It works fine.

We can ping each other, DNS resolution "seems" to be ok, it resolves to the right IP.

When using IP address of the DC4 (-I option) instead of the name (-S), it works...

```
/usr/bin/net ads join -I 10.0.0.26 -U DomainUser
```

Have anyone seen something like this?

Comment: `DC4.Somedomain.local` is out of sync with the domain, misconfigured, or otherwise not properly registered in DNS.

I'd wager that any computer you try to join to the domain by contacting `DC4.Somedomain.local` will result in failure.  As to what exactly is wrong, who knows.  Check the logs on DC4, verify replication between domain controllers, etc., etc.